# IIS8 why might an HttpModule not be loaded?

Tags: httpmodule, iis-8

I have an HttpModule which has been successfully implemented in a number of sites. I am trying to implement it on a Windows 8 PC under IIS 8 and it is not being loaded. The configuration is as follows:

- The Application pool is running Integrated mode with .Net 4.0
- The dll has been compiled using .Net 4.0
- The dll has been correctly registered in the system.webServer section of web.config (this is not a problem with using the old system.web config section and classic mode).
- The module correctly displays in IIS manager under Modules, and in fact was registered using the user interface.
- The web application is also loading an IsapiModule - (the SQL Server Analysis Services msmdpump) and this is working correctly.

For reference the web.config section is as follows.

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="MyModule" type="MyModule.ClassName" />
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I am wondering, are there any new global options in IIS8 that could disable managed HttpModules by default?